# Ошибка сборки программы Cmake

Tags: ubuntu, cmake, kubuntu

добрый день! Нужно установить на Ubuntu программу [OpenDroneMap](https://github.com/OpenDroneMap/OpenDroneMap)

Всё делаю точно по инструкции, но при сборки возникают ошибки типа

```
 CMake Error at cmake/safe_execute_process.cmake:11 (message):
    execute_process(/usr/bin/python
    "/media/don/D62AD01A2ACFF591/OpenDroneMap/SuperBuild/build/catkin   /catkin_generated/generate_cached_setup.py")
  returned error code 1
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/all.cmake:186 (safe_execute_process)
  CMakeLists.txt:8 (include)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/media/don/D62AD01A2ACFF591/OpenDroneMap/SuperBuild/build/catkin/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
make[2]: *** [catkin/stamp/catkin-configure] Ошибка 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/catkin.dir/all] Ошибка 2
make: *** [all] Ошибка 2
Script finished
```

В логах ничего про ошибки не написано, как мне кажется где-то не создаются какие-то дирректории.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема. может что-то в настройках CMake?

Comment: `$ /usr/bin/python --version`?

Comment: Вот Python 2.7.6

Comment: файловая система на этом носителе, случайно, не *fat* какой-нибудь? такими вещами, как компиляция, лучше заниматься на [полноценной файловой системе](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D1%83%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%BA_%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83_%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2).

Comment: спасибо за наводку, сейчас проверю, возможно... я потом отпишусь

Comment: дело было в файловой системе, на том разделе стояла ntfs, я перенёс всё на ext4 и всё с первого раза заработало. alexander barakin, большое вам спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

дело было в файловой системе, на том разделе стояла ntfs, я перенёс всё на ext4 и всё с первого раза заработало. alexander barakin, большое вам спасибо!

Comment: чтобы ответ был полезен другим, имеет смысл в ответе написать причину — отсутствие case-sensitivity. это, кстати, довольно «стандартная» ситуация. даже на ru.so я уже пару раз встречал вопросы, вызванные этой же проблемой.

Comment: я банально ничего не могу добавить, нужно смотреть на какйо файловой системе вы компилируете, вот и всё, так как видимо из-за этого могут быть проблемы.